# Am I going to have trouble flying without my full name on the ticket?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, qatar-airways

In my passport, my name is Firstname middlename1 middlename2 lastname, and in the ticket is LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME MR.

Will be a problem? I'll travel from Brazil to Bali, Indonesia and according to the agency I bought the ticket from, there's no problem and it's common.

The airline is Qatar Airlines and I have looked [this link](https://qatarairways.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/206459948-Can-I-change-a-passenger-s-name-in-an-award-ticket-at-any-time-), which says that the passenger name can't be changed after the booking has finished.

But I don't know if it is a problem.

Comment: After being admonished to include my full middle name by United, they just print it as (e.g. given 'Fred Rogers Smith') "Smith, Fredr"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's fine, as long as the first and last name are correct. I also have several middle names that I never use anywhere, and it has never caused any problems.

Comment: Even if it appear in the passport?

Comment: @fdam: yes, they're all in my passport

Comment: @fdam yes, like many people in France I have several middle names, they appear in my passport, and they never appear on plane tickets, and I’ve never had a problem on any of the 5 continents.

Comment: And also note that many Indonesians in Bali are in the same situations, having long (more than 3 words) name, which usually don't fit in the ticket.

Comment: Yup.  My documentation is <first><middle><last>, I've flown on <first><last> tickets before.

Comment: @fdam , my flight name has always been ericugomez,  my real name is thrice as longer as that and has spaces. don't worry about that.

Comment: Often my ticket is RRIBEIRO, and I have 4 names...Your are overthinking things.

Answer (score 3):

I have two surnames. Usually, my tickets have only last surname and first name. Also, I  already had tickets printed my first name and my two last names without space. I never had any issue on that.

Answer (score 3):

Before I ask this question here I sent an e-mail to Qatar Airlines and they also answer my question as below:

> Dear,
>
> Thank you for contacting Qatar Airways.
>
> With regard to your email, please be advised that Qatar Airways check
>   in counter will be checking the first name and last name of the
>   passenger only, thus if passenger has a multiple names or middle names
>   which are not reflecting in the ticket, it is still considered as good
>   for travel.
>
> We thank you for taking the time to communicate with us and we look
>   forward to welcome you aboard.
>
> Yours sincerely, Qatar Airways Support